# How to exclude transitive dependency from liberty-server build.gradle file

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I got 2 java projects and 1 server all three having build.gradle file defining and configuring the dependencies I need in my project.
Code snippet of Liberty server build.gradle is as follows:

```
configuration{
  project1
  project2
  oracle
  extrasecuritystuff
}

dependencies{
  project1: "fskfksd"

  project2: "sdfd"

  extrasecuritystuff 1."fsfd"
                     2."ewrwer"
}
doTask{....
```

My question is how do I exclude a transitive dependency present in 2."ewrwer". What is the groovy/gradle syntax for doing so?
Based on the gradle docs I tried something like this but did not work out, once I triggered the Jenkins build It was still pulling in the transitive dependency jars.

```
   configurations {
           project1
           project2
           extrasecuritystuff {
            exclude group: 'javax.jms', module: 'jms'
            exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk', module: 'jmxtools'
           }
    }

    dependencies {
      project1 'org.javax.etc' 
      project2 'org.blah.blah'   
      extrasecuritystuff 'log4j:log4j:1.2.15'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you are using some plugin like the 'application' plugin to generate a .zip file of your project, and that your goal is to exclude the transitive dependency from the .zip file. The reason could be that the transitive dependency has an undesirable license, or is too large, and your code is never actually calling functions that need the transitive dependency. (Make absolutely 100% double sure of this, or your application will crash.) Or, the target system already has that dependency installed. (Likewise.)

You had a few syntax issues in your example code, but I've interpreted the question according to my understanding. In the example, my dependency `ewrwer` is pulling in `lib-foo` which I don't want.

```
configuration{
  project1
  project2
  extrasecuritystuff
}

dependencies{
  project1 ( [...] )
  project2 ( [...] )

  extrasecuritystuff ('org.blah:fsfd:1.0.1')
  extrasecuritystuff ('org.bloop:ewrwer:2.12') {
       exclude group: 'org.bleep', module: 'lib-foo'
  }
}
```

For more about managing transitive dependencies, as always refer to [the official Gradle docs.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html)